# how to show recently viewed product after main content

Tags: magento2, recently-viewed

i am want to show recently viewed product on all pages after main content.

i have added new widget from Widgets option its working fine but its showing before main content on all pages:
[image]

But i am want to show it after main content.

Admin setting screenshot

[image]

Please help

Comment: you can set the layout in widget before the footer

Comment: please show your widget settings from admin

Comment: admin setting screenshot: https://prnt.sc/qf0cwe